# how to use html to pass varabile to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a tic-tac-toe game.I'm having trouble making a function that will work on all 9 buttons. I plain to down the road make it so when they are clicked they are on clickable and puts and  img on the button x if odd o if even.But before I do that I want to make even thing to what it should and including win right now I am stuck on passing the variable to JavaScript.
here is the html

```js
var box1 = box2 = box3 = box4 = box5 = box6 = box7 = box8 = box9 = false;
var turn = 0;

function Box() {
  if (box1 == false) {
    document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML = 1;
  } else {
    null;
  }
}
```

```css
#box1 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 150px;
}

#box2 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 150px;
}

#box3 {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 150px;
}

#box4 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 250px;
}

#box5 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 250px;
}

#box6 {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 250px;
}

#box7 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 350px;
}

#box8 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 350px;
}

#box9 {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 350px;
}

#reset {
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px;
  top: 475px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TicTacToe</title>
  <LINK href="board.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="tic.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="tictactoe">
    <button id="box1" onclick="Box(box1)"> </button>
    <button id="box2" onclick="Box(2)"> </button>
    <button id="box3" onclick="Box(3)"> </button>
    <button id="box4" onclick="Box(4)"> </button>
    <button id="box5" onclick="Box(5)"> </button>
    <button id="box6" onclick="Box(6)"> </button>
    <button id="box7" onclick="Box(7)"> </button>
    <button id="box8" onclick="Box(8)"> </button>
    <button id="box9" onclick="Box(9)"> </button>
  </div>
  <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">reset</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are passing a value in your `onclick="Box(2)"` but you aren't catching that value because your javascript is `function Box()`.  Change the function declaration to `function Box(boxId)` and now `boxId` has the 2 in it.

Comment: that worked till I added the else if statements `else if(box2==false){document.getElementById("box2").innerHTML=2;}'

Comment: Well, that was why you weren't getting the value into your js function.  Your issue now is that your base logic needs work.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the data-* element and some jQuery to simply store your image path.

Something like this:

```
  <button id="box1" data-image="/img/yourimage.jpg" onclick="Box(box1)"> </button>

 var imagepath = $( "button" ).data( "image");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. I add a listener to each button using jquery.

To add the image of the x or o, tyou just need to style the classes added with the same name. You can use `background-image`

If you have any other problem, i am happy to help;

```js
var box1 = box2 = box3 = box4 = box5 = box6 = box7 = box8 = box9 = false;
var turn = 0;

function Box() {
  if (box1 == false) {
    document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML = 1;
  } else {
    null;
  }
}

var x = true;

$('.box').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    if (x) {
      $(this).addClass("x");
      x = false;
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("o");
      x = true;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#box1 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 150px;
}

#box2 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 150px;
}

#box3 {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 150px;
}

#box4 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 250px;
}

#box5 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 250px;
}

#box6 {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 250px;
}

#box7 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 350px;
}

#box8 {
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 350px;
}

#box9 {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 350px;
}

#reset {
  position: absolute;
  left: 230px;
  top: 475px;
}

.x {
  background-color: red;
}

.o {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TicTacToe</title>
  <LINK href="board.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="tic.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="tictactoe">
    <button id="box1" class="box" onclick="Box(box1)"> </button>
    <button id="box2" class="box" onclick="Box(2)"> </button>
    <button id="box3" class="box" onclick="Box(3)"> </button>
    <button id="box4" class="box" onclick="Box(4)"> </button>
    <button id="box5" class="box" onclick="Box(5)"> </button>
    <button id="box6" class="box" onclick="Box(6)"> </button>
    <button id="box7" class="box" onclick="Box(7)"> </button>
    <button id="box8" class="box" onclick="Box(8)"> </button>
    <button id="box9" class="box" onclick="Box(9)"> </button>
  </div>
  <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">reset</button>

</body>

</html>
```